# Can't install adventure works on sql server express 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

First of all, I am new to SQL and I am using virtual box on my mac to run Windows 10 for SSMS.

I have installed sql server 2014 express and I wanted to install adventure works OLTP script 2012 on it. It didn't work. I followed the instructions but it always ended up with:

> Msg 5123, Level 16, State 1, Line 92 CREATE FILE encountered operating
>   system error 5(access is denied) ....

I am aware it is related to an access problem but I don't know how to change it.

Can you help me please, with specific details on how to process where to go etc.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: "access denied". ssms can't read that script file for whatever reason.

Comment: Have you checked [here?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22250/sql-server-create-file-encountered-operating-system-error-5-access-is-denied) Same concept.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answers, I actually managed to install Adventures works 2012 by installing the adventureworks2012_data file. I copied the file here:

C:\program files\microsoft sql server\mssql12.sqlexpress\msql\data\

Then I went on SSMS, right clicked on databases, attach, add, then found the file I just copied in the path above, clicked ok, then refreshed the database.

Voilà.